# Unable to retrieve multiple data from firebase into card view/ list view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

I am working on a firebase application & i got stuck while retrieving the database into cardview/listview.

Here is a demo look to the firebase database.

```
   db
   |- 001
       |- details
            |- key1: "value1"

            |- key2: "value2"

            |- key3:
                |- key3_1: "value3_1"

            |- key4:
                |- key4_1: "value4_1"
```

This is a demo database but exactly the same as per my requirements.
Here i want to retrieve every key-value pair. I tried it by first passing the database reference then in child i mention "/db" based on above example. Then i tried to fetch the data but it didn't work for above example. Anyone interested out there please share your ideas on this!

Any answer or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("001").child("details");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String key1 = dataSnapshot.child("key1").getValue(String.class);
        String key2 = dataSnapshot.child("key2").getValue(String.class);
        //and so on
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

You output wil be:

```
value1
value2
value3
//and so on
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using `ds.child(...)` looks wrong given that `ds` is *already* a `"details"` child node.

Comment: I have removed the last loop. Thanks Paulo. See my updated answer.